# Do I have private lessons or classes with a private teacher?

Tags: word-in-context

Let's suppose I have a private English teacher. Do I have English lessons or English classes with him or her? Is the word class used only to talk about a group environment? Or can I use it for individual teaching? What's the correct word in each context?

Comment: Related question: [Opposite of private tutoring lessons](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/124516/9161) - it doesn't answer this question explicitly, but might be interesting for people interested in this question.

Answer (score 1):

This somewhat depends on where you are - in my experience, Americans use the term *classes* for this sort of thing much more than Brits. However, that aside, in my experience both *private classes* and *private lessons* are acceptable, but *private lessons* is more usual - and judging by reports, that's true on both sides of the Atlantic.

Comment: Thanks SamBC. Just to make sure I got the first part of your answre right, you mean that Americans use the word classes for individual teaching more than Brits?

Comment: Yes. To us, a *class* is more usually a group of people (or other things). The group of kids who have a lesson together in school are a *class*, but we tend to use *lesson* for the actual teaching session. Or *lecture* or *seminar* or *workshop*, in non-school contexts. Americans also use *class* for a module at university or an option at school. We tend to call it a *course* or a *module*. Education is one area where the usual vocabulary is very different.

Comment: @Zenildo I'm an American, but I would use the term class for a group teaching session and lessons for a one-on-one or very small group situation. It's been a long time since I've been one, but I'm pretty sure high school kids in the US would talk about "going to class (or classes)" and "taking" private lessons (for example, with a tutor).

Comment: Yeah, ngram suggests that, with the word *private* in front, *lessons* beats *classes* on both sides of the Atlantic.

Comment: Count me as another American agreeing with Don B.  We may indeed use *classes* more liberally than British people, but I have a hard time imagining someone saying, "I'm going to my piano class," or "I have a math class with a tutor after school."

Comment: Thanks folks, added a note to that effect.

Comment: FWIW I think the difference is somewhere in that phrase "I'm going to class" which your average BrE speaker would not say. They'd treat it as a countable noun and also tend to be more specific. "I'm going to my maths lesson", "I'm going to a lecture". An AmE speaker may say "piano lesson" too but it's that uncountable "class" that stands out to British ears. That and the fact "school" is university or college.